# Error with .map Function Tensorflow Dataset

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, tensorflow, keras, arguments

I am trying to import a directory full of images into Tensorflow and then use it for Keras Tuner. The problem is Keras Tuner requires the data to be split into images and labels. I was following a guide on Tensorflow's website and here is the code I have so far:

NOTE: I am using the COCO dataset meaning each image has multiple labels. Maybe that is the problem.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import IPython.display as display
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
import PIL
import os
import pathlib
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import cv2
import datetime
import kerastuner as kt

tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
tf.executing_eagerly()

epochs = 50
steps_per_epoch = 10
batch_size = 10
IMG_HEIGHT = 150
IMG_WIDTH = 150

train_dir = "Data/Train"
test_dir = "Data/Val"

train_data_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_dir, labels='inferred', label_mode='int',
    class_names=None, color_mode='rgb', batch_size=batch_size, image_size=(IMG_HEIGHT,
                                                                           IMG_WIDTH), shuffle=True, seed=None,
    validation_split=None, subset=None,
    interpolation='bilinear', follow_links=False
)

test_data_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    test_dir, labels='inferred', label_mode='int',
    class_names=None, color_mode='rgb', batch_size=batch_size, image_size=(IMG_HEIGHT,
                                                                           IMG_WIDTH), shuffle=True, seed=None,
    validation_split=None, subset=None,
    interpolation='bilinear', follow_links=False
)

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1. / 255)

train_data_gen = train_data_gen.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
test_data_gen = test_data_gen.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_data_gen = train_data_gen.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
test_data_gen = test_data_gen.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

train_dir_PATH = pathlib.Path(train_dir)

class_names = np.array(sorted([item.name for item in train_dir_PATH.glob('*') if item.name != "LICENSE.txt"]))
print(class_names)


def get_label(file_path):
    # convert the path to a list of path components
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
    # The second to last is the class-directory
    one_hot = parts[-2] == class_names
    # Integer encode the label
    return tf.argmax(one_hot)


def decode_img(img):
    # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    # resize the image to the desired size
    return tf.image.resize(img, [IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH])


def process_path(file_path):
    label = get_label(file_path)
    # load the raw data from the file as a string
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = decode_img(img)

    return img, label

train_ds_map = train_data_gen.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds_map = test_data_gen.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

for image, label in train_data_gen.take(1):
  print("Image shape: ", image.numpy().shape)
  print("Label: ", label.numpy())

# train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
#
# test_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
#
# train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
#                                                            directory=train_dir,
#                                                            shuffle=True,
#                                                            target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
#                                                            class_mode='sparse')
#
# test_data_gen = test_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
#                                                          directory=test_dir,
#                                                          shuffle=True,
#                                                          target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
#                                                          class_mode='sparse')

def configure_for_performance(ds):
  ds = ds.cache()
  ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
  ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
  return ds

train_data_gen = configure_for_performance(train_data_gen)
test_data_gen = configure_for_performance(test_data_gen)

def model_builder(hp):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(265, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"))
    hp_units = hp.Int('units', min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32)
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(hp_units, activation="relu"))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(80, activation="softmax"))

    hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])

    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
                  loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=['sparse_top_k_categorical_accuracy'])

    return model


tuner = kt.Hyperband(model_builder,
                     objective='top_k_categorical_accuracy',
                     max_epochs=30,
                     factor=3,
                     directory='Hypertuner_Dir',
                     project_name='AIOS')

stop_early = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)

for image, label in train_data_gen.take(1):
    print("Image shape: ", image.numpy().shape)
    print("Label: ", label.numpy())

tuner.search(image_batch_n, labels_batch_n, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[stop_early])

# Get the optimal hyperparameters
best_hps=tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]

print(f"""
The hyperparameter search is complete. The optimal number of units in the first densely-connected
layer is {best_hps.get('units')} and the optimal learning rate for the optimizer
is {best_hps.get('learning_rate')}.
""")

model = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)

# model.summary()
# tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file="model.png", show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True, rankdir='TB')
checkpoint_path = "training/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)

os.system("rm -r logs")

log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

history = model.fit(train_data_gen,steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,epochs=epochs,validation_data=test_data_gen,validation_steps=10,callbacks=[cp_callback, tensorboard_callback])
#history = model.fit(train_ds, epochs=epochs,validation_split=0.2)

val_acc_per_epoch = history.history['top_k_categorical_accuracy']
best_epoch = val_acc_per_epoch.index(max(val_acc_per_epoch)) + 1
print('Best epoch: %d' % (best_epoch,))

hypermodel = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)

# Retrain the model
history = hypermodel.fit(train_data_gen,steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,epochs=epochs,validation_data=test_data_gen,validation_steps=10,callbacks=[cp_callback, tensorboard_callback])

# model.load_weights(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))
# model.save('model.h5', include_optimizer=True)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_data_gen)
print("Tested Acc: ", test_acc)
print("Tested Acc: ", test_acc*100, "%")
```

When I try to run `train_ds_map = train_data_gen.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)` it throws the following error:

My data is structured like this:

```
Train
    - Class 1
    - Class 2
    - Class 3
    - Class ....
    - Class 80
Test
    - Class 1
    - Class 2
    - Class 3
    - Class ....
    - Class 80
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AIOS_Hypertune.py", line 90, in <module>
    train_ds_map = train_data_gen.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
  File "/home/dragonos/anaconda3/envs/AIOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1807, in map
    return ParallelMapDataset(
  File "/home/dragonos/anaconda3/envs/AIOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 4242, in __init__
    self._map_func = StructuredFunctionWrapper(
  File "/home/dragonos/anaconda3/envs/AIOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3525, in __init__
    self._function = wrapper_fn.get_concrete_function()
  File "/home/dragonos/anaconda3/envs/AIOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3051, in get_concrete_function
    graph_function = self._get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(
  File "/home/dragonos/anaconda3/envs/AIOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3019, in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/dragonos/anaconda3/envs/AIOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/dragonos/anaconda3/envs/AIOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3196, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "/home/dragonos/anaconda3/envs/AIOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/dragonos/anaconda3/envs/AIOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3518, in wrapper_fn
    ret = _wrapper_helper(*args)
  File "/home/dragonos/anaconda3/envs/AIOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3453, in _wrapper_helper
    ret = autograph.tf_convert(func, ag_ctx)(*nested_args)
  File "/home/dragonos/anaconda3/envs/AIOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 670, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
TypeError: in user code:


    TypeError: tf__process_path() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

How can I fix this error? The only thing I can think of is because of each of my images having multiple classes.

Comment: Seam that train_data_gen contains more than just the filepath. Can you check it? E.g. with for data in train_data_gen.take(1): print(data).  In your case it will also make sence to apply the cache and fetching after mapping function.

Comment: Please see how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the Train and Test split like this:

```
train_data_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_dir, labels='inferred', label_mode='int',
    class_names=None, color_mode='rgb', batch_size=batch_size, image_size=(IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH), shuffle=True, seed=123,
    validation_split=Val_Split, subset="training",
    interpolation='bilinear', follow_links=False
)

test_data_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_dir, labels='inferred', label_mode='int',
    class_names=None, color_mode='rgb', batch_size=batch_size, image_size=(IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH), shuffle=True, seed=123,
    validation_split=Val_Split, subset="validation",
    interpolation='bilinear', follow_links=False
)

.........

list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(train_dir_PATH/'*/*'), shuffle=False)
list_ds = list_ds.shuffle(image_count, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)

val_size = int(image_count * Val_Split)
train_data_gen = list_ds.skip(val_size)
test_data_gen = list_ds.take(val_size)
```

This worked for me. Just follow this guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images